# Google is marking as duplicate my unique URLs powered by Angular Universal

Tags: google, web-crawlers, googlebot, angular.js

I have a problem in the search console, and google is marking my unique urls as duplicate

The application is build with Angular Universal and is rendered in the server

[image]

[image]

Note: This site is only created for testing purposes and educational ones such as building a crawler, playing with server side rendering of SPA's, SEO learning.

I cannot find where is the problem in this case, since each of my link is unique, and they all include the **rel="canonical"** tag

Comment: "is rendered in the server" -- I don't think that is working.   If I visit https://putlocker.mk/movie/5561/austin-powers-the-spy-who-shagged-me and view source I see a generic title tag for your site.   All the content appears to loaded via AJAX.

Comment: Yes, I use ajax to get the content from Ajax, what do you think is the problem,

Comment: Then it is the same problem as https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121459/javascript-rendered-translated-versions-of-pages-not-indexed-separately

Comment: Alright, so you suggest only to wait few months ?

Comment: Or better yet don't use angular.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help Stephen, I appreciate it