# JavaScript rendered translated versions of pages not indexed separately

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, internationalization

My app serves local content from separate subdomains. eg: fr.example.com serves content for french users, www.example.com for global etc. The content on the page is javascript rendered. if I check pages in "fetch as google", I get to see the correct javascript rendered version in "This is how Googlebot saw the page:" section. The pages from different subdomain are set with separate canonicals, and hreflangs. this is how hreflangs are defined

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/about" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://fr.example.com/about" hreflang="fr" />
```

Hreflangs are also defined in sitemap.xml

The problem is  google indexes only the en version. Checking in the search console I see this "Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user".
How do we get google to consider these as 2 separate pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wait a couple months.  Google will render your pages and find their full content eventually.  However [it takes Googlebot weeks to render pages after it crawls them](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-speed-up-crawl-to-render-time-27150.html).   In the meantime, it renders the text only version.  When your content is JavaScript rendered, the HTML source code that Googlebot initially sees is very simple and duplicate.

Because of this, I would not recommending using JavaScript frameworks such as React and Angular to build a website that requires SEO.    Loading all the content via AJAX can make good websites that are usable, but there are significant problems getting them indexed in search engines.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, your link answered a question of why Google displays old content in the SERPs even though I know it has crawled more recent content.

Comment: Thanks, this could be the reason because I have tried all the other suggestions mentioned in other articles, discussions etc. Although I cannot be 100% sure (because it will take some weeks for the second pass), I am marking this as the answer, because this is a new information for me, which I never considered in such cases.